# I would like to color my pie but the #numbers doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: r, pie-chart

I would like to color my pie but the #numbers doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?
The code gives the pie but with other colors. I am using the package "Palmerpenguins" in R.

```
slices <- c (146,119,68)
lbls <- c ("Adelie 146", "Gentoo 119", "Chinstrap 68")
clrs <- c ("#527f85", "#f08fff", "#7d9cf6")

pie(slices, labels= lbls, main= "Aantallen Pinguins per soort", clockwise = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include `col = clrs` :

```
slices <- c (146,119,68)
lbls <- c ("Adelie 146", "Gentoo 119", "Chinstrap 68")
clrs <- c ("#527f85", "#f08fff", "#7d9cf6")

pie(slices, labels= lbls, main= "Aantallen Pinguins per soort", 
    clockwise = TRUE, col = clrs)
```

[image]